# Why is the heavy/light hole band not called heavy/light electron band?

Tags: semiconductor-physics

Are the bands called heavy hole, light hole and electron band, just because the charge carriers are holes/electrons or is there some deeper reason I missed?

The question might seem stupid, but it led to some confusion here and I just could not find an answer to it...

Comment: Are you asking about hole vs electron, or light vs heavy for the holes but not electrons?

Comment: I'm wondering about hole VS electron naming of bands, light and heavy was just an example

Comment: OK then. The quantities of interest for calculating the semiconductor properties are how many conduction electrons are in the conduction band (coming from dopants or the valance band), and how many holes are in the valence band (coming from dopants). You track the holes, because those are the spots that a conduction electron can drop into, resulting in carrier recombination.  The electron-hole balance is the basis for the thermodynamic understanding of equilibrium carrier concentrations, which then allows for understanding devices. So, we focus on the holes in the valence band.

Comment: Ok thanks so far. Assuming we lower the Fermi level to the band below the current valence band, would the remaining (doping) electrons have the same band structure as the holes had when the Fermi level was at its original height? And how can I close a topic, as you answered my question ;-) do you want to write your text as answer so I could accept it formally for you?

Comment: You can't lower the Fermi level into the valence band. The valence band in an intrinsic semiconductor at 0K is completely full of electrons.  Above 0K and with doping you can get some of the electrons to move up, leaving holes in the sea of electrons.  Those holes are what we track. The valence band is still mostly full of electrons.